# EF - cast int(short) to string with copability Linq expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Default DTO model class:

```
public class Test
{
    public short Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Legacy DB with name type as Number(5).

```
CREATE TABLE SCHEME.TABLE_NAME
(
    ID   NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
    NAME NUMBER(5) NOT NULL
)
```

Example:

```
public dynamic GetResult(string searchString)
{
    return DbContext.Set<Test>()
                    .Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchString))
                    .FirstOfDefault();
}
```

How to create mapping for field `Test` for available query Entity Framework? Because without normal mapping EF mean string type as normally but cannot create normally query SQL to get same data.

Comment: It's hard to get what you mean. Do you mean you want to find records where Name contains , for example, "34", and then find "12345", "23412", etc?

Comment: Yes. But without convert to string property type I cant to compare as string but concertation in Linq does not support at EntityFramework 6. I haven`t idea. 
Mapping convert - not supported.
Using other insted if EF - I cant. 
Create query as sql and load data and compare - cant because have a lot of logic and DTO in repository.

Comment: You can use `.Where(x => x.Name.ToString().Contains(searchString))`, although it's not optimal (it can't use indexes).

Comment: I cant use Linq *Contains*, because is not supported in LinqToDb query (for Int type I meen). Linq cant to translate Contains from Int type to string immideatly in Expression. And if you use cast type - Linq can´t compare too (can´t supported casting value type from not mapped field in Expression query).

Comment: Please add this all to your question. Also, LinqToDb? You didn't use that tag. It's *not* Entity Framework.

Comment: I mean Linq to DB as System.Func with System.Linq.Expression whom create lambda tree expression and next cast this to sql query in EntityFramework. 
At now EntityFramework 6 cannot supported cast int ot string in lambda without mapping.  But and mapping i don´t now, how to cast model type int to string non after select query (before i mean).